# Signing/certificate VSTO Outlook plugin

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

I am having a hard time understanding the process of signing / certifying Outlook plugin.

The problem is that plugin works but I can't install it on all machines. On some it can be installed and on some not (it gives security alert about manifest not signed/certified). I have gone through docs but I can't say its clear for me.

What is the easiest way to fix that problem? Could someone explain it in a few, plain english, words?

Comment: Are you using a click-once install?

Comment: no, we used windows installer.

Comment: It should work for both. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: yes yes, will try and give feedback. thank you very much!

Comment: no worries, VSTO is one of my favourite type of projects. I have a bunch of examples in GitHub https://github.com/Office-projects

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Comment: oh, i am sorry! i got dragged into other things and completey forgotten to do it. thanks a lot for reminder!

Comment: No worries mate, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First you want to create a non-expiring certificate for Visual Studio projects

Type `Developer Command` in the Start Menu search and right click and select <kbd>Run as administrator</kbd>

[image: Start Menu]

Paste the following commands in the command prompt for [MakeCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [pvk2pfx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
MakeCert /n "CN=Your New Cert" /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e "01/01/2100" /sv MyNewCert.pvk MyNewCert.cer 
pvk2pfx -pvk MyNewCert.pvk -spc MyNewCert.cer -pfx MyNewCert.pfx
```

**Note:**

- The date format is the US standard `MM/DD/YYYY`
- The `-f` parameter can be used at the end of the pvk2pfx line for overwriting an existing file
- You'll get prompted to create a password (this is optional)

[image: cmd prompt]

After the password prompt, you'll need to run the second command line by just pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image: cmd prompt2]

### Now you can select the same certificate for multiple Visual Studio projects

In the Visual Studio project properties, select <kbd>Signing*</kbd> click on <kbd>Select from File…</kbd>.
Navigate to the same path from the command prompt and select the certificate file (*.pfx)

[image: Visual Studio Signing]